# Layout Event on a custom Panel User Control

Tags: c#

I'm currently working on a custom user control inheriting from a panel, I'm trying to hook on the Layout event of the Panel to do a certain action. I don't want to override the initial Layout event, I just want to hook on it and add stuffs to do

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SamsonLogiciel
{
    public partial class StretchPanel : Panel
    {
        public StretchPanel()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what event you want and where is you tried code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
protected override void OnLayout(LayoutEventArgs levent)
{
    // your code here
    base.OnLayout(levent);
}
```

Just add this to your `StretchPanel` class. You can add your own code to "hook" into it, and then you call `base.OnLayout` so that you don't override the default stuff.

Comment: I just had the same problem... weird... +1

Comment: @Raphy963 When you're able, consider marking my answer as the accepted solution since it seems to work. I'm glad I could help!